# Use contacts from Data Extension as Subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, import, cloud

I am importing contacts from a Salesforce custom object into a exacttarget data extension. Is there a way to automatically set those contacts as subscribers?

The goal is to always have an up-to-date contact list in the marketing cloud and use those contacts in the journey builder. I don't want to use FTP or manual steps.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an Import Activity you can map the email field to the subscriber key field. Then a subscriber is being created (or updated).

Make sure to have the Subscriber Key feature enabled